# How to I set the meta description or meta keywords on a new page in WordPress using the REST API

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a ClearScript enabled JavaScript interpreter. I have wrapped RestSharp and am using it to do REST calls. I have created an object to talk to WordPress. Running it looks like this

```
var wpi = new WordPressSharp();
wpi.Url('some url');
wpi.Username('some username');
wpi.Password('some password');

wpi.Endpoint('pages');
wpi.Body("status", "draft");
wpi.Body("slug", "some slug");
wpi.Body("title", "some title");
wpi.Body("content", some_html);
var ans = wpi.Post();
```

I won't bore you with the implementation of the object because it's not germane to the question. Rather, I'm trying to find out how to transmit meta-description and meta-keywords settings.

I have tried a number of different approaches, all of which generating an error of the

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): meta","data":{"status":400,"params":{"meta":"Invalid parameter."}}}
```

kind.

What actually needs to be there? Currently I have have

```
wpi.Body("meta", JSON.stringify([{
                "key": "description",
                "value": "some description"
            }
        ]));
```

which is going nowhere.

Comment: Are you using any plugin, like Yoast SEO?

Comment: I'm wanting to avoid using a plugin as I'm creating large numbers of pages from spreadsheeted data.

Comment: WordPressSharp is a XML-RPC Client for C#.net. If we go to [XML-RPC WordPress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API), can't find any component that could relate to meta descriptions or meta keywords. Yet, it might be possible to extend its behavior to match what one wants - https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending.

Comment: Then I should rename my tool as "WordPressInteraction" and save people drawing a non-existent connection between my code and the XML-RPC API.

Comment: Does [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-post-with-meta-field-wp-rest-api/) help?

Comment: Sorta not. The issue for me is how to effect that registration from within the admin panel of a WordPress site. The other is problem is a niggling doubt that we are talking about the same thing when we use the word /meta/. I'm talking about items in the `<HEAD>` that start with `<META`. I get the impression that WordPress has another kind of meta.

Comment: «Meta keywords and description are actually HTML meta tags», in [WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-keywords-and-meta-descriptions-in-wordpress/).